# How to stop a swing timer

Tags: java, swing, animation, timer, actionlistener

I am working on a GUI. This is the code (one `ActionListener` for `Button` and one for `timer`). I have a list of images to display one by one. On pressing a `stop` button, i am supposed to stop the timer and display the current image. On pressing the `next` button, i am supposed to display the next image.

This is the part of a code on `Progressive Image Transmission` which means displaying each of the current image in an order of clarity(resolution). This is what handler action Listener does for each image.

Problems:

- On Clicking stop, the timer is not stopping, rather stop's action listener is further creating more timers i guess.(Note : Next and Stop share same Action Listeners)
- On clicking next,  the present running timer needs to be stopped and a fresh timer needs to be started. (Note : I used timer.restart() but it also didnt serve the purpose)

Help would be appreciated.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    int threads=0;

    System.out.println("Listening : "+arg0.getActionCommand());
    if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("Send")){
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        nextButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
    else if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("Stop")){
        timer.stop();
        saveButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
    else if(arg0.getActionCommand().equals("Next")){
        stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
        timer.restart();
    }
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(new File(pathName[imageNo])).getScaledInstance(512,512 , BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);

    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    senderImage = new ImageIcon(image);
    senderImageLabel.setIcon(senderImage);
    senderFrame.setVisible(true);

    ImageToMatrix(getImage(pathName[imageNo]));
    Compress();
    k=senderMatrix.length-1;
    imageR=Decompress(k);
    imageR=imageR.getScaledInstance(512, 512, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    receivedImage = new ImageIcon(imageR);
    receiverImageLabel.setIcon(receivedImage);
    receiverFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,receiverImageLabel);
    receiverFrame.setVisible(true);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    timer = new Timer(1000,handler);
    timer.start();
    sendButton.setEnabled(false);

    imageNo = (imageNo+1)%5;
}
class Handler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("image: "+imageNo+"  matrix:"+k );
        k-=1;
        imageR=Decompress(k);
        imageR=imageR.getScaledInstance(512, 512, BufferedImage.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        receivedImage = new ImageIcon(imageR);
        receiverImageLabel.setIcon(receivedImage);
        receiverFrame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.EAST,receiverImageLabel);
        receiverFrame.setVisible(true);
        if(k==0){
            timer.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which Timer class are you using?

Comment: Why are you creating a new timer in the `actionPerformed`? Use the same timer.

Comment: yeah right @peeskillet .. That solved the problem